# "A silver dollar, find a handkerchief marked ... " - what is the "find a"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, literature

I am readíing some tales from C.A. Smith, and found the following sentence:

> A silver dollar, find a handkerchief marked with Buckingham's
> initials, were also round not far from the note-book.

I do not get it, what is the function of the "find a handkerchief" part?

Comment: "round" is probably "found", on top of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't manage to find the original 1930 issue of "Amazing Detective Tales", but [the 1941 reprint of the story in "Tales of Wonder"](https://archive.org/details/tales_of_wonder_and_super_science_number_14_1941/page/n41/mode/2up) prints the sentence as:

> A silver dollar **and** a handkerchief...

As such, the word "find" is probably a transcription error.

Comment: Ah, I guess you are right, I discovered a few more errors that seems like OCR problems. Thanks a lot!